# Polite way to approach boss about salary?

Tags: management, salary

About 2 or 3 months ago I had been hired by a software firm as an intern. Upon talking with HR around that time, they told me that they would start paying me once clients started coming in (it's a startup firm), which would be around April. It is now April, we have been receiving clients, and I want to ask my boss for a pay stub, so I can plan accordingly and apply for student loans if necessary to finish my degree.

Whats the most polite way I can approach my boss about this matter?

Comment: By "ask my boss for a pay stub" do you mean get an estimate on what you will make or are you wanting to be paid now? You may have clients, but are they paying?

Comment: They are paying. In fact the company is in a hiring phase, so they do have funds. I mean a paystub as in an estimate.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are - but "internships" on the promise of a paid job are illegal in Australia and the UK. Internships are supposed to let you gain experience and educate you. If they're not doing that and they're dangling future pay at you, then go get a real job that actually pays.

Comment: with another offer in hands, from another job, it's easier to talk about this subject IMO

Comment: By "get a paystub" do you mean "get a paycheque"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slight re-arrangement of your question that should be polite enough to ask directly:

> Hi Boss, when you brought me on-board it was agreed that you would
>   start paying me once clients started coming in, with the expectation that that  would be around  April. We have now been receiving clients, and I would like to have a
>   pay stub so that I can plan accordingly and apply for student loans,
>   if necessary, to finish my degree.